# Ruby on Rails - SLIM - SCSS - inject ruby variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, slim-lang

How do I set a SCSS variable based on ruby variable value?

Following code is working for CSS but not for SCSS:

```
- primaryColor = app.theme_variables['primary-color'];
= content_for(:after_head_script) do
  css:
   .primaryColor {
     color: #{primaryColor};
   }
```

If I do same thing with SCSS:

```
- primaryColor = app.theme_variables['primary-color'];
= content_for(:after_head_script) do
  scss:
    $color = #{primaryColor}

    .primaryColor {
      color: $color;
    }
```

output is as follows:

```
.primaryColor{color:primaryColor}
```

So any idea on how to inject variable into SCSS?

Comment: This is a just a hunch, but have you tried wrapping the interpolation in double-quotes? e.g. `$color = "#{primaryColor}"`

Comment: Yea I did.  Same reault.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't seem to work in Slim, which is a bummer. At least you have the `css:` variant to fallback on.

Comment: Yes I do have css, but main problem is that I want to use SCSS functions like darken().

Comment: what about if you make of color a dynamic value getting it from the database and output it by passing its id, or in a loop?

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, it's not supported.

Iterpolated are:

- ruby
- javascript
- css
- markdown
- textile
- rdoc

And these are not:

- sass/scss
- less
- coffee

As described here: https://github.com/slim-template/slim#embedded-engines-markdown-

Answer (score -1):

Add a .slim extension to your .scss file and your variable expansions should work (i.e., ".scss.slim").

See [Asset Pipeline Preprocessing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) for details.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use standard ERB interpolation inside scss directives, not sure if there is a slim-er way.

```
scss:
  $color = <%= primaryColor %>;
```